# Why dynamically created html element's title is not reached by ".title"?

Tags: javascript, html

I create new html element. And initialize its value. Then when I try to reach for its title by `el.title`, it returns `undefined`. However I can reach by `getElementsByTagName("title")`

The example is below;

```
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>HTML Reference</title></head><body>The content of the document......</body></html>";

console.log(el.title)
**undefined**

//but the following returns the title 
el.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].text
"HTML Reference"
```

Why this is happening? Why `el.title` returns `undefined`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `title` property of an HTML element object maps on to [the `title` **attribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title), it doesn't find the first title **element** descendant.

You would get a result if you had `<html title='bad place for a title'>`

Comment: side note: `document.title` will return title tag value: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_title.asp

Comment: @Pepo_rasta — It will return the title for the actual document and not the HTML element and its descendants that were just created.